# Finding every instance of XML Element in SQL output

Tags: sql, xml, ssms

I'm a beginner when it comes to SQL and have no experience with XML so I'm after a little bit of help.

At the moment I am looking at a single table and just using the query below

```
select 
name, 
convert(xml, convert(varbinary(max), orders)) ClientOrders 
from client;
```

In the second columns of SQL output, I have a very lengthy bit of XML similar to the example below. I've used "..." just to skip over some of the output and give a general idea.

| Name | ClientOrders |
| --- | --- |
| Client1 | `<report ... ><QueryParameter></QueryParameter Name = "@hello1"><commandtext> ...<value>Example1</value>....<value>Example2</value>...<value>Example3</value>...</commandtext></report>` |
| Client2 | `<report ... ><QueryParameter></QueryParameter Name = "@hello2"><commandtext> ...<value>Example4</value>....<value>Example5</value>...<value>Example6</value>...</commandtext></report>` |

I have this for a lot of rows and this output is so long that it exceeds the Excel cell character limit. I'm only looking for the values Example1 through to Example6 in the example given above. Is there an SQL command I can run to get the above string between the open and close value?

I am using SSMS version 18.9.1

Cheers

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, thank you for letting me know some more of the rules :) I will update accordingly